# Rust: argument requires that `[VARIABLE]` is borrowed for `'static`

Tags: rust

I get this unhelpful error message:

```
error[E0597]: `msg` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:25:23
   |
25 |         let msg_str = msg.as_str();
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                       |
   |                       borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                       argument requires that `msg` is borrowed for `'static`
...
51 |     }
   |     - `msg` dropped here while still borrowed
```

From the following Rust code:

```rust
    for msg in rx {
        let msg_str = msg.as_str();
        let msg_type = get_msg_type(exchange, &msg_str);

        println!("{}", &msg_str);

        let join_handle = spawn_blocking(move || { parse_trade(exchange, market_type, &msg_str) });
        match join_handle.await {
            Ok(trade) => {
                let t = &trade.unwrap()[0];
            },
            Err(error) => panic!("Problem joining: {:?}", error),
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't tell me how to do a `static` borrow of `msg` in this case.

**What is a viable solution here?**

None of the following proposed duplicate questions are equivalent to this question:

1. [Spawn non-static future with Tokio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65269738/spawn-non-static-future-with-tokio)
2. [Can you specify a non-static lifetime for threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57643084/can-you-specify-a-non-static-lifetime-for-threads)
3. [How do I use static lifetimes with threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562443/how-do-i-use-static-lifetimes-with-threads)
4. [How can I send non-static data to a thread in Rust and is it needed in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437174/how-can-i-send-non-static-data-to-a-thread-in-rust-and-is-it-needed-in-this-exam)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I have a good idea on what's going on here, but I can't help you without knowing what the type of `msg`, `msg_str` and the method parameter types of `get_msg_type` and `parse_trade` are.
It should be fairly straightforward to convert this into a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Finomnis: It's not a "minimal" example, but it should be small enough: https://github.com/nhooey/crypto-arbitrage-rs/blob/master/src/main.rs

Comment: I don't think this is a minimal example. Please break down your code to the absolute minimum required to produce that error.
I updated my response with a guess of a minimal example, together with a proposed solution.
Please read the guide on how to create a minimal reproducible example, in most cases the process of creating such an example brings you to the solution already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `msg` is a variable you get from the iteration, and therefore is only valid during one iteration step. It ceases to exist at the end of the iteration step, hence the comiler message `- msg dropped here while still borrowed` at the end of the loop.

The reason why this is a problem is because you move the reference `msg_str` into the closure via `move ||`, and the rust compiler cannot infer that `spawn_blocking` drops it before the end of the loop. (it can't infer it because it would be incorrect; `join_handle.await` could get cancelled, which would NOT cancel the spawned task and would cause `&msg_str` to be a dangling reference)

---

> But it doesn't tell me how to do a `static` borrow of `msg` in this case.

You can't borrow statically from a temporal variable. That is the definition of a `'static` borrow, that it does not cease to exist after a while.

---

Sadly without knowing the types of the variables / function parameters I can't give you any advice how you could solve this. You probably want to introduce a clone somewhere, but hard to tell where exactly without knowing types.

---

**Guess of a solution**

I tried to infer a minimal reproducible example from your question.
I assume that the types are as followed:

```rust
use tokio::task::spawn_blocking;

fn parse_trade(_msg: &str) -> Result<Vec<u32>, String> {
    Ok(vec![1, 2, 3])
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let rx = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string()];

    for msg in rx {
        let msg_str = msg.as_str();

        println!("{}", &msg_str);

        let join_handle = spawn_blocking(move || parse_trade(&msg_str));
        match join_handle.await {
            Ok(trade) => {
                let t = &trade.unwrap()[0];
            }
            Err(error) => panic!("Problem joining: {:?}", error),
        }
    }
}
```

Which does show the following error message:

```
error[E0597]: `msg` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:12:23
   |
12 |         let msg_str = msg.as_str();
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                       |
   |                       borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                       argument requires that `msg` is borrowed for `'static`
...
23 |     }
   |     - `msg` dropped here while still borrowed
```

This is a possible solution:

```rust
use tokio::task::spawn_blocking;

fn parse_trade(_msg: &str) -> Result<Vec<u32>, String> {
    Ok(vec![1, 2, 3])
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let rx = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string()];

    for msg in rx {
        let msg_str = msg.as_str();
        let msg_clone = msg.clone();

        println!("{}", &msg_str);

        let join_handle = spawn_blocking(move || parse_trade(msg_clone.as_str()));
        match join_handle.await {
            Ok(trade) => {
                let t = &trade.unwrap()[0];
            }
            Err(error) => panic!("Problem joining: {:?}", error),
        }
    }
}
```

You create a `.clone()` of `msg` and move this one into the closure instead. It carries ownership of the cloned string into the closure, and it therefore does no longer depend on the `msg` variable.

Comment: Your suggestion of creating `msg_clone` worked!

Comment: I'm glad :)
Please try to understand how my minimal example is set up, and try to imitate that in future. That would have saved me a bunch of time :)