# Creating an asynchronous task from a method, from within a method of the same structure

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-async-std

How can one method of a structure run another method of the same structure as a task?

Forgive me for possible stupidity, I'm new to Rust.
The compiler complains that `self` cannot survive the body of the function in which it is called. But isn't this accessing the context of a structure that is, by definition, alive, since its methods can be called?

```rust
use std::time::{Duration};
use async_std::{task, task::JoinHandle, prelude::*};


async fn sleep(delay: f64) -> () {
    task::sleep(Duration::from_secs_f64(delay)).await;
}

struct TestTask {
    item: usize,
    count: usize
}

impl TestTask {
    fn new() -> TestTask {
        return Self { item: 0, count: 0 }
    }

    async fn task(&mut self, delay: f64) -> () {
        sleep(delay).await;
        println!("AFTER SLEEP {}sec, value = {}", delay, self.item);
        self.item += 1;
    }

    fn create_task(&mut self, delay: f64) -> () {
        task::spawn(self.task(delay));
        self.count += 1;
    }
}

async fn test_task() -> () {
    let mut obj = TestTask::new();
    let delay: f64 = 5.0;
    obj.create_task(delay);

    sleep(delay + 1.0).await;
    println!("DELAY SLEEP {:?}sec", delay + 1.0);
}

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
    test_task().await;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `task::spawn` [here](https://docs.rs/async-std/latest/async_std/task/fn.spawn.html) requires that the future passed to it be bounded by `'static`. This isn't the case since `&mut self` has a non-static lifetime. It's because `async_std` typically uses a multi-threaded an executor, and even though you can configure it to use a single thread, the `task::spawn` API still enforces the `'static` bound.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: For additional clarity, the async executor can move tasks between threads in it's async thread pool. So fwiw if you had configured a single-threaded executor then the `'static` bound is unnecessarily restrictive. But otherwise it's there because in Rust, without scoped threads, the compiler can't reason about the lifetimes of things you send into other threads.

Comment: I feel like this question comes up every couple of days (spawning a thread/task with a reference), yet I can't seem to find a proper duplicate...

Comment: @Finomnis possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72182515/rust-argument-requires-that-variable-is-borrowed-for-static) (which you answered), or one of the duplicates linked there.

Comment: @Jmb Maybe I should create a dummy question and answer that shows this in its pure form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem:**

The compiler does not know if the task created in create_task ever ends. This is a problem because after spawn is called the task runs asynchronously from the rest of the program. So it is possible that `self.count += 1` will run first (this is most likely to happen), but on the other hand `self.item += 1` can also run first. The problem here is that `self.item += 1` could be executed so late that the original object has already been deallocated and the reference to it is only a dangling pointer.

**Reference Counters:**

One possibility would be to wrap the object in a reference counter, so that its lifetime would no longer be determined statically by the compiler but would be decided dynamically during runtime.

```
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio;
use tokio::time;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::atomic::Ordering;
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicUsize;

#[derive(Default, Debug)]
struct TestTask {
    item: AtomicUsize,
    count: AtomicUsize
}


impl TestTask {
    async fn task(self: Arc<TestTask>, delay: f64) {
        let duration = Duration::from_secs_f64(delay);
        time::sleep(duration).await;
        println!(
            "AFTER SLEEP {}sec, value = {}",
            delay,
            self.item.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed)
        )
    }
    
    fn create_task(self: Arc<TestTask>, delay: f64) {
        tokio::spawn(self.clone().task(delay));
        self.count.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let obj = Arc::new(TestTask::default());
    let delay: f64 = 5.0;
    obj.create_task(delay);
    
    time::sleep(Duration::from_secs_f64(delay + 1.0)).await;
    println!("DELAY SLEEP {:?}sec", delay + 1.0);
}
```

I used tokio here because `async_std` is not available in the playground. If usize is required instead of it‘s atomic counterpart the object needs to be wrapped in a mutex.

You may also want look into scoped threads, which effectively allow you to pass non static references into different threads or tasks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a comprehensive answer!