# Understanding "argument requires that `variable` is borrowed for `'static`"

Tags: rust

I am completely new to rust but have prior experience in C and I have this rust code which does not compile.

```rust
use std::fs;

static mut GRAPH_BUILDER: Option<Box<[&[u8]; 2]>> = None;

#[export_name = "wizer.initialize"]
pub extern "C" fn init() {
    let weights = fs::read("./mobilenet.bin").unwrap();
    let xml = fs::read_to_string("./mobilenet.xml").unwrap().into_bytes();
    let input: [&[u8]; 2] = [&weights, &xml];

    unsafe {
        GRAPH_BUILDER = Some(Box::new(input));
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    unsafe {
        if GRAPH_BUILDER.is_none() {
            init();
        }
    }
}
```

When compiled with `rustc main.rs` It produces these errors

```
error[E0597]: `weights` does not live long enough
  --> main.rs:9:30
   |
9  |     let input: [&[u8]; 2] = [&weights, &xml];
   |                              ^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
12 |         GRAPH_BUILDER = Some(Box::new(input));
   |                              --------------- argument requires that `weights` is borrowed for `'static`
13 |     }
14 | }
   | - `weights` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0597]: `xml` does not live long enough
  --> main.rs:9:40
   |
9  |     let input: [&[u8]; 2] = [&weights, &xml];
   |                                        ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
12 |         GRAPH_BUILDER = Some(Box::new(input));
   |                              --------------- argument requires that `xml` is borrowed for `'static`
13 |     }
14 | }
   | - `xml` dropped here while still borrowed

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
```

I understand that this error is caused because `weights` is stored on the stack and will be unallocated when the `init` function terminates, so the static `GRAPH_BUILDER` would contain a pointer to unallocated memory. So I tried to use a `Box` instead, which from my understanding should act like malloc in C. But it does not seem to work. How can I get rust to allocate the `weights` and `xml` variables on the heap, without knowing their sizes at compile time? I.e. What is the rust-equivalent of malloc?

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72182515/rust-argument-requires-that-variable-is-borrowed-for-static) that you can call `clone` to fix this problem. But I don't want to do it because the files I read in are large. And I also don't understand why that would fix the problem. Wouldn't the clone just end up on the stack too?

**EDIT**: Another important thing I should mention, I need to provide `GRAPH_BUILDER` as an argument to the [wasi_nn::load](https://docs.rs/wasi-nn/0.3.0/wasi_nn/fn.load.html) function, and it essentially expects it to be of the datatype slice `&[&[u8]]`. But I have absolutely no idea how to convert it to this datatype. Here is the continuation of the main function.

```rust
use wasi_nn;

pub extern "C" fn main() {
    bench::start();
    let context: wasi_nn::GraphExecutionContext;
    unsafe {
        if GRAPH_BUILDER.is_none() {
            init();
        }
    }

    let graph = unsafe {
        wasi_nn::load(
            &GRAPH_BUILDER.expect("Graph builder was not initialized"),
            wasi_nn::GRAPH_ENCODING_OPENVINO,
            wasi_nn::EXECUTION_TARGET_CPU,
        )
        .unwrap()
    };
```

I am trying to modify [this](https://github.com/bytecodealliance/sightglass/blob/1731a9660e9700998f4ed0b7551b4c30489a5b1b/benchmarks/image-classification/rust-benchmark/src/main.rs#L15) code such that it creates `&[&xml.into_bytes(), &weights]` in an initialization function instead of passing it directly.

Comment: Using `static mut` is almost always a mistake, especially if you're a beginner.

Comment: If that is because it is not thread safe, it is not a big issue because this is just a test program that is not meant to ever be multithreaded.

Comment: It is not just it not being thread safe. And even in test program it is better to follow best practices.

Comment: And those best practices are? As it stands you have just been telling me that I am doing things wrong without suggesting what I should do instead.

Comment: Use a thread local, or use a `static` with `Mutex`.

Comment: Thanks, thread locals seem a lot better that using `unsafe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the rust-equivalent of malloc?

That is a completely unnecessary question, you don't need to dig further, you need to actually look at your code and think about what's happening.

Rust's `&T` is not a C-style wild pointer, it's a lexically-scoped borrowing smart pointer. It can only refer to data that is *lexically* valid for its entire lifespan.

> So I tried to use a Box instead, which from my understanding should act like malloc in C. But it does not seem to work.

Well no, because inside your box you're still putting *references to function-local data*. Which is what Rust is complaining about.

You're not copying or moving that data to the heap you're just adding an indirection to the exact same issue: when the function ends, `weights` and `xml` are still going to be dropped, and the references you put inside your `Box` will still be dangling, which Rust does not allow.

But `weights` and `xml` are `Vec<u8>` so they're already owned, heap-allocated data types. All you need to do is *move* them into your thing:

```rust
static mut GRAPH_BUILDER: Option<(Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>)> = None;

[...]

        GRAPH_BUILDER = Some((weights, xml));
```

Also you want to `unwrap` in an `extern C` function even less than in a Rust function. To my knowledge, at best that will summarily abort, at worst it's UB.

Comment: Thank you, your solution does compile. I realized though that I needed to add some more context to my question, which I have now done. Is there a way to convert between `(Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>)` and `[&[u8]]`?

Comment: An unrelated question, if `xml` and `weight` are `Vec<u8>` and `Vec<u8>` is a heap-allocated data type, then theoretically they don't need to be dropped at the end of the init function (Assuming I assigned a pointer to them to a static variable). In C I would just not `free` them, can this be achieved in Rust too?

Comment: Why do you want to perform such a conversion? Also why are you so intent on trying to get perpetual references? No offense but you seem rather insistant on bad ideas and working against the language.

Comment: Did you check the edit I did in the original question? If the wasi_nn::load function wants a `&[&[u8]]` then what am i supposed to do about it, apart converting the input to that datatype? It's not as if I am trying to work against the language.

Comment: @Mechakhan no I'd not seen it. You can just create a slice at load time by borrowing the owned vecs, something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6b8bed18f350d28f930fd8dabecd09ed), the function takes slices of references but it doesn't actually keep a reference so that should not be an issue. I've no idea why you would want to go from all-safe all-sensible all-locals to a global mutable static tho. Some sort of cache?

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly! Yes, the reason I'm doing this is to essentially cache the initialization code using a tool called Wizer which is meant to pre-initialize WebAssembly modules for faster startup.